# Question about the set of all non-recursively enumerable languages

Tags: computability, automata

Is the set of all non-recursively enumerable languages uncountable or countable? Proof? (I would assume it is uncountable but not sure.)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: There are uncountably many languages total, and only countably many r.e. languages, so . . .

(More generally, it's a good rule of thumb that "most" languages aren't "simple".)

Comment: Noah: thanks for the hint.  I see it now.